# How do I encrypt nerves project files on memory card?

Tags: raspberry-pi, elixir, nerves-project

When I burn memory card by mix.burn. Anybody can read content of my card by simple usb reader. I have sensitive keys and authentication credentials on memory. how do I encrypt or obfuscate the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nerves supports encrypted filesystems through the Linux kernel (corrected).

Raspberry Pi is not a platform I would consider appropriate for shipping to production as a product without some physical protection.  It can still be useful for prototyping, though.  For production, you would typically move to a more hardened platform with onboard flash.

Even then however, you should avoid baking authentication credentials into your firmware.  Look into certificate-based authentication where certificates are provisioned to each device during or prior to production.

If that's too heavy handed then look into using access tokens through OAuth 2.0 which can be used as a proxy for credentials and revoked independently of them.  This will require more interaction from the end user, so that's a tradeoff you would need to consider.

Comment: Check out the Compute Module for Raspberry Pi.  It has eMMC built in: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md

Comment: I updated my comments to reflect some corrections and assumptions that I made.

Comment: Also, BeagleBone Black!